# Cómo lematizar en español una string con NLTK?

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de lematizar en español usando la libreria nltk para tener un texto más limpio para ser usado más tarde en TensorFlow 2.0.

```py
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

#(...)
#lematizar el texto a español
```

La string que tengo ha sido filtrada y tokenizada previamente, por lo que queda son únicamente palabras sueltas listas para ser lematizadas.

Si no existe alguna manera de hacerlo con esta librería en español, por favor avisarme para cambiar el título y buscar alguna otra solución.

Comment: No se si actualmente con omw, nltk permite lematizar en español, llevo tiempo si usarlo y tendría que probar... Si no tienes inconvenientes si se seguro que [spacy](https://spacy.io/) puede hacerlo porque lo estoy usando en un pequeño proyecto personal (hay [dos modelos](https://spacy.io/models/es) en español de hecho disponibles)

Comment: @FJSevilla si, al parecer con NLTK no permite lematizar al español, y, confirmo, con el Spacy si es posible hacerlo en español.

Answer (score 2):

en nltk no hay (que yo sepa)
pero puedes usar uralicNLP (lo recomiendo mucho)
ejemplo:

```
from uralicNLP import uralicApi
print(uralicApi.lemmatize("poder","spa"))
```

sin embargo uralicNLP solo puede lematizar una sola palabra, "poder" es la palabra y "spa" es el idioma (spanish), si quieres hacer el proceso para todas las palabras podrias hacer:

[uralicNLP.lemmatize(e, "spa") for e in tokens]

Answer (score 1):

Lematizador en NLTK no hay(que yo sepa), pero para stemming usa

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
spanish_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('spanish')
(spanish_stemmer.stem("texto_en_str"))
```

Comment: Si efectivamente en NLTK no hay, finalmente terminé usando [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/index.html), realmente lo recomiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Exacto, no hay una implementacion en nltk para español, solo para el stem. Pero puedes probar usando spaCy https://spacy.io/usage.

Comment: Buenas, por favor explica dentro de la respuesta la información necesaria. Puedes leer [answer] para tener una mejor idea.